# Parallelising function that updates numpy matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, parallel-processing, numba

Suppose I have a function that takes in a 4D matrix and 4 other arrays and does an update of the matrix entries:

```
@njit
def func(matrix, A, B, C, D):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(B)):
            for k in range(len(C)):
                for l in range(len(D)):
                    matrix[i][j][k][l] = another_func(A[i], B[j], C[k], D[l])
```

An example of `another_func` is of the form below:

```
def another_func(a, b, c, d)
    if c <= 5:
        return b
    else:
        return 1 + d * (c - a) + (b - d)
```

Is there a way to parallelise these updates or ways to speed it up more?

I tried using numba's @njit but the speedup's not good enough.

Comment: without extra information on `another_func` there is not much to help besides that your whole loop is parallelizable considering `another_func` is independent for each element. Maybe, you can provide us with more information about your function

Comment: Is `another_func` also `njit`?

Comment: Done updated the ```another_func```

Comment: Please fix `another_func` to show what it actually does to it's inputs. Right now it looks like it operates per-row

Comment: Oh sorry, typo. Edited it!

Comment: Can you please just show it as a `def` so I can copy an MCVE into my editor instead of playing guessing games?

Comment: Done, edited the another_func

Comment: Can you show what you have done? Input arrays and timings... eg. You likely have njitted another func, but there are also some other things eg(inline="always") which could be important here.

Comment: How about setting cache=True? That should improve the runtime by more than twice at least.